# Increase security of DB INSERT

Tags: sql-injection, database

Currently, I have a PostGIS DB, and I have the basics working. However, I am inserting directly into the database using `pg_query`. I have been recommended to use `pg_query_params` to help prevent against SQL injections, but am unsure how to implement this. Below is a cut-down example of my current `insert` statement for a site location. How would I, for example, utilise `pg_query_params` with this example? I know I will have to implement further security, but it is a starting point.

EDIT: I was going to use the drupal form API but it gave me headaches. I realize that would do a lot of this stuff automatically.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sites_tbl (river_id ,sitename ,the_geom) VALUES ('$_POST[river_id]','$_POST[sitename]',st_geomfromtext('POINT($geomstring)',27700))";
$result = pg_query($sql);
```

Comment: This is better suited for stackoverflow,  also this query is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: I had it on there and then I was told to put it here. My question does say I am looking to prevent sql injection on the query....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using strings rather than parameters, your example is vulnerable to SQL injection. It's best to avoid `pg_` functions. In your case there are two things you need to take into account:

- Learn the Drupal API (considering you are using Drupal this would be the best for code consistency

or

- Use [stored procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql.html)
- Use a library like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php) or [pg_query_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) which takes care of [parameterized queries](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.1)

Normally you use stored procedures in addition to PDO, unfortunately sometimes this is not manageable because you have too much code. My advice is to use as much stored procedures as possible.

Comment: So I couldn't just convert the insert to utilise params? I am researching the drupal form api now

Comment: I've added the page for pg_query_params